# Clarification of monerod config defaults

Tags: monerod, daemon, linux

I am trying to template the whole Monero config file. I can't figure out what the default of different variables are.
From my understanding there are three different types of defaults, for example:

- `detach`
- `pidfile arg`
- `max-concurrency arg (=0)`

The first one seems like a flag, where 0 is false and 1 is true.

The second and third contain `arg`, which means you can provide an argument I guess. The third provides an default for that.

Now my question is, how do I specify the default value for variables that have no default listed in the documentation? Do I have to just not put it in the config at all, or can I set the value to 0 or -1?

I found a [different post](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7197/what-is-the-default-behavior-of-monerod-concerning-the-max-concurrency-flag?r=SearchResults) that does not fully answer my question but is maybe related.

Answer (score 0):

For Monero config variables without defaults, explicitly assign a non-zero value or valid argument during setup to avoid potential issues.

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically want the fallback default, as if the variable is not set in the config, to handle unset template variables.